# How to load own libraries in ZF2?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I want to develop my own libraries in ZF2, but I have a problem when I try to use my own classes.

I have create my own classes (SistemaData.php) inside this folder structure

[image]

**SistemasData.class**

```
namespace Data;

class SistemasData{
    public function __construct($log){
        $log->info("Hola desde dentro del constructor!!!");
    }
}
```

**/Vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php**

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'phpDocumentor' => array($vendorDir . '/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/src'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
    'ZendDeveloperTools' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/src'),
    'Prophecy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/phpspec/prophecy/src'),
    'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Instantiator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/instantiator/src'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/cache/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib'),
    'DoctrineORMModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src'),
    'DoctrineModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-module/src'),
    'Demo31\\'  => array($vendorDir . '/Demo31')
);
```

**FooController.php**

```
use Data\SistemasData;

class FooController{
  public function indexAction(){
      $sistemas = new SistemasData($log);
  }
}
```

**Error**

> Class 'Data\SistemasData' not found in
>   /var/www/html/gnsys/module/Publico/src/Publico/Controller/ActividadesController.php

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit 1:**

Following the instructions of Alex P, I have made these changes:

1. I have change the namespace Demo31 -> Demo

[image]

2. I have create a new class for this example

**BubbleSort.class**

```
namespace Sort;

class BubbleSort{
    public function __construct($log){
        $log->info("Hola desde dentro del constructor de BubbleSort!!!");
    }
}
```

3. I have modified autoload_namespaces.php

**/Vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php**

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'phpDocumentor' => array($vendorDir . '/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/src'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
    'ZendDeveloperTools' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/src'),
    'Prophecy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/phpspec/prophecy/src'),
    'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Instantiator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/instantiator/src'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/cache/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib'),
    'DoctrineORMModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src'),
    'DoctrineModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-module/src'),
    'Demo\\'    => array($vendorDir . '/Demo/library')
);
```

And the result is ...

> Fatal error: Class 'Sort\BubbleSort' not found in
>   /var/www/html/gnsys/module/Publico/src/Publico/Controller/ActividadesController.php
>   on line 31

**Edit 2:**

I have run php composer.phar dumpautoload and it doesn't work but this process has delete the line added by me. Right now, my autoload_namespaces.php:

```
$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'phpDocumentor' => array($vendorDir . '/phpdocumentor/reflection-docblock/src'),
    'ZendXml' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zendxml/library'),
    'ZendDeveloperTools' => array($vendorDir . '/zendframework/zend-developer-tools/src'),
    'Prophecy\\' => array($vendorDir . '/phpspec/prophecy/src'),
    'PHPExcel' => array($vendorDir . '/phpoffice/phpexcel/Classes'),
    'Doctrine\\ORM\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/orm/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Instantiator\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/instantiator/src'),
    'Doctrine\\DBAL\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/dbal/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Lexer\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/lexer/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Inflector\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/inflector/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Collections\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/collections/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Cache\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/cache/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\Annotations\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/annotations/lib'),
    'Doctrine\\Common\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/common/lib'),
    'DoctrineORMModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-orm-module/src'),
    'DoctrineModule\\' => array($vendorDir . '/doctrine/doctrine-module/src'),
);
```

What happened with this line?

```
'Demo\\'    => array($vendorDir . '/Demo/library')
```

**Edit 3:**

I don't know why but the files has not been changed. Now is 22h19' and the files have a distinct hour.

[image]

**Solution**

I have found the solution. These are the steps to follow:

Create the folder structure that you desire, for example:

[image]

Create our object BubbleSort.php, for example:

```
namespace Sort;

class BubbleSort{
    public function __construct($log){
        $log->info("Hola desde dentro del constructor de BubbleSort!!!");
    }
}
```

Edit composer.json file which is inside of your project and append this block of code:

```
"autoload":{
    "classmap": ["vendor/Demo/library"]
}
```

At the end of your file.

**componser.json**

```
{
    "name": "zendframework/skeleton-application",
    "description": "Skeleton Application for ZF2",
    "license": "BSD-3-Clause",
    "keywords": [
        "framework",
        "zf2"
    ],
    "homepage": "http://framework.zend.com/",
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5",
        "zendframework/zendframework": "~2.5",
        "zendframework/zend-developer-tools": "dev-master",
        "doctrine/doctrine-module": "^0.9.0",
        "doctrine/doctrine-orm-module": "^0.9.2",
        "phpoffice/phpexcel": "^1.8"
    },
    "autoload":{
        "classmap": ["vendor/Demo/library"]
    }
}
```

The next step is to run php composer.phar dumpautoload. Important "dumpautoload" to not update all the libraries of your project!!!

And finally, you can make a little test create an instance of the object in the indexAction of a controller, for example

**FooController.php**

```
use Sort\BubbleSort;

class FooController{
public function indexAction(){

        $log = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("Zend/Log");
        $a = new BubbleSort($log);

        return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Comment: The file path should read `$vendorDir . '/Demo31/library'` to work. Just append `/library` to the autoload config in composer.json and run `php composer.phar dumpautoload` The namespace should also be `Demo` not `Demo31`.

Comment: Thank you!!! But I can't run php composer.phar because I don't want to update all my libraries!!!

Comment: @JoséCarlos running `php composer.phar dumpautoload` will not update all your libraries, it will just regenerate your autolading files

Comment: @marcosh Thank you!!! I'm trying rigth now!!!